# Is there way to get SQL to launch a C# application

Tags: c#, sql

I am making an application, I would like to be able to get a script to put data into the database, but i was wondering can i get SQL to Launch a C# application to get information from the web and return that into the database without having to interact with the SQL database.

Realistically I would like the operation to run like so:

```
Query -> Launch c# -> input the data to DB
```

but i would like this all to work from the initial procedure, is something like this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a program from SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162663/how-to-run-a-program-from-sql)

Comment: DBAs everywhere will genuinely hate you if you do this... in almost any scenario, the flow should be "C# fetches / formats data from external source -> C# invokes SQL -> SQL stores (or whatever) the data". There *is* a capability to run .NET directly inside SQL Server, but : that is *also* no longer recommended, and is disabled by default on new versions, IIRC

Comment: Look at Sql clr integration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-clr-functions?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It it not favoured practice but you can use the below stored procedure to call a C# executable. Some times it is unavoidable if you are constrained.

```
xp_cmdshell { 'command_string' } [ , no_output ]
```

[You can find the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)